# Extract the file name 'yyyymmdd.csv' and display the string 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Tags: datetime, python-3.6, datetime-format

I want to output the string '2019-12-03'

=====

```
filename="20191203_volum.csv"
yyyy=filename[:4];print(yyyy)  
mm=filename[5:6];print(mm)  
dd=filename[7:8];print(dd)  
yyyymmdd=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd
print(yyyymmdd)

#I want to output the string '2019-12-03'
# '2019-12-03'

#The result of the program which does not go as expected is the following.
# '2019-2-3'
```

=====
I took out yyyy, mm, dd respectively. And joined.
However, the result was different from the expectation.

- mm = 12 but 2
- dd = 03 but it became 3.


  How should I write a program? I would like you to tell me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the date in your filename is *always* before `_`, you could:

1. extract the date as a string,
2. parse the string to get a `datetime` object,
3. then format it the way you want.

It would go as follow:

```py
from datetime import datetime

filename = '20191203_volum.csv'
parts = filename.split('_')
str_date = parts[0]

my_date = datetime.strptime(str_date, "%Y%m%d")
formatted_date = my_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(formatted_date)
# '2019-12-03'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
The answers from the new direction, and the method I was taught have become very studied. 
1, 2 went well. However, in 3 I got an error. The error is below.   

ValueError: time data '%Y%m%d' does not match format '20191203'

Comment: It worked well if 3 was made as follows. I'm really thankful to you.

Comment: datetime.strptime(str(str_date), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: oh sorry, glad you figure it out, I mixed up everything :) also https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html is always useful!

Comment: Thank you for telling me more information. That was a really big help.